# How to align center text that next to a span?

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment, vertical-alignment

I am trying to put "per month" vertical-align to the price "$29" just like the picture.You can help me fix my code or give me a new way that is better for me.

This is what I want.

[image]

This is what I had

[image]

here is my HTML code.

```
  <div class="deal">
          <span class="price">&dollar;29</span>
          <span class="period">per month</span>
        </div>
```

and my css.

```
.price {
  font-size: 50px;
}
.monthly {
  color: #d0d3d4;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.deal{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
.period{
  margin-left:0.5rem;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Markov88/1a3vybos/13/)

Comment: I tried your code and it work, but when I delete margin-left:0.5rem; it still works perfectly. Can you explain what does margin-left:0.5rem do?

Comment: Becouse stay too close each to other thats why i write this magin-left:0,5rem;

Answer (score 2):

```
.deal {
display: inline-flex;
align-items: center;
}
```